# Is using CSS media queries the correct way for making parallax site responsive?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, parallax

I have built a parallax website.

Here is the demo link. The link should stay for a week(at least) from the date I posted my question.
http://divizbeta.in.s3-website-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/

So, it works fine for viewport resolution of 1366px by 768px. Now, the problem starts when I reduce the screen width. Because, with decreased width, the height increases.
The skrollr data-attributes are defined in percentage like for example something like

```html
<div id="wizard-1" style="-o-backface-visibility:hidden;-o-perspective:1000;"
data-0p="position:absolute;top:13%;left:35%;" 
data-50p="position:absolute;top:45%;left:60%;" 
data-100p="position:absolute;top:86%;left:105%;">
    <img src="img/02.png" alt="">
</div>

So, this is fine for 768px height and 1366px. But when height increases, the percentage does not change responsively. So, with greater height, the html element simply does not / cannot have the same effect has that in 1366px.

One work around for this that I thought was, if I can define different skrollr divs for different resolutions and then hide and unhide the skrollr divs using CSS media queries. Something like this:

<!-- moon shadow on water -->  
<div id="moon-shadow-for-plus800px" class="island-bg-6" style="position:absolute;z-index:99999999999;left:-30%;top:0;-ms-transform:scale(1);-webkit-transform:scale(1);transform:scale(1);" 
data-0="position:absolute;z-index:99999999999;left:-30%;top:0;-ms-transform:scale(1);-webkit-transform:scale(1);transform:scale(1);"
data-2100p=""
data-3100p="position:absolute;z-index:99999999999;left:-32%;top:0%;-ms-transform:scale(1.1);-webkit-transform:scale(1.1);transform:scale(1.1);"
data-4100p="position:absolute;z-index:99999999999;left:-34%;top:2%;-ms-transform:scale(1.5);-webkit-transform:scale(1.5);transform:scale(1.5);"
data-4600p="position:absolute;z-index:99999999999;left:-36%;top:5%;-ms-transform:scale(1.6);-webkit-transform:scale(1.6);transform:scale(1.6);">
            <img src="img/night bg/4.png" alt="">
</div>
         
<!-- moon shadow on water -->  
<div id="moon-shadow-for-1000px" class="island-bg-6" style="position:absolute;z-index:99999999999;left:-50%;top:0;-ms-transform:scale(1);-webkit-transform:scale(1);transform:scale(1);" 
data-0="position:absolute;z-index:99999999999;left:-50%;top:0;-ms-transform:scale(1);-webkit-transform:scale(1);transform:scale(1);"
data-2100p=""
data-3100p="position:absolute;z-index:99999999999;left:-52%;top:0%;-ms-transform:scale(1.1);-webkit-transform:scale(1.1);transform:scale(1.1);"
data-4100p="position:absolute;z-index:99999999999;left:-54%;top:2%;-ms-transform:scale(1.5);-webkit-transform:scale(1.5);transform:scale(1.5);"
data-4600p="position:absolute;z-index:99999999999;left:-56%;top:5%;-ms-transform:scale(1.6);-webkit-transform:scale(1.6);transform:scale(1.6);"
>
  <img src="img/night bg/4.png" alt="">
</div>

<!-- moon shadow on water -->  
<div id="moon-shadow-for-900px" class="island-bg-6" style="position:absolute;z-index:99999999999;left:-60%;top:0;-ms-transform:scale(1);-webkit-transform:scale(1);transform:scale(1);" 
data-0="position:absolute;z-index:99999999999;left:-60%;top:0;-ms-transform:scale(1);-webkit-transform:scale(1);transform:scale(1);"
data-2100p=""
data-3100p="position:absolute;z-index:99999999999;left:-62%;top:0%;-ms-transform:scale(1.1);-webkit-transform:scale(1.1);transform:scale(1.1);"
data-4100p="position:absolute;z-index:99999999999;left:-64%;top:2%;-ms-transform:scale(1.5);-webkit-transform:scale(1.5);transform:scale(1.5);"
data-4600p="position:absolute;z-index:99999999999;left:-66%;top:5%;-ms-transform:scale(1.6);-webkit-transform:scale(1.6);transform:scale(1.6);">
    <img src="img/night bg/4.png" alt="">
</div>
         
<!-- moon shadow on water -->  
<div id="moon-shadow-for-800pxless" class="island-bg-6" style="position:absolute;z-index:99999999999;left:-70%;top:0;-ms-transform:scale(1);-webkit-transform:scale(1);transform:scale(1);" 
data-0="position:absolute;z-index:99999999999;left:-70%;top:0;-ms-transform:scale(1);-webkit-transform:scale(1);transform:scale(1);"
data-2100p=""
data-3100p="position:absolute;z-index:99999999999;left:-72%;top:0%;-ms-transform:scale(1.1);-webkit-transform:scale(1.1);transform:scale(1.1);"
data-4100p="position:absolute;z-index:99999999999;left:-74%;top:2%;-ms-transform:scale(1.5);-webkit-transform:scale(1.5);transform:scale(1.5);"
data-4600p="position:absolute;z-index:99999999999;left:-76%;top:5%;-ms-transform:scale(1.6);-webkit-transform:scale(1.6);transform:scale(1.6);">
 <img src="img/night bg/4.png" alt="">
</div>
```

And then the CSS goes like this:

```css
    @media only screen and (min-width:1100px) and (max-width:1243px){
    .pegasus{
     width:70%;
     position:absolute;
     top:10%;z-index:9;left:15%;
    }
    .pegasus img{
     position:relative;
     left:-1%;width:100%;
    }
    .blue-band{
     width:100%;
     position:absolute;top:80%;
     background-color:transparent;z-index:9;
    }
    
    #moon-for-800px,#moon-shadow-for-800pxless,#moon-for-900px,#moon-shadow-for-900px,#moon-for-1000px,#moon-shadow-for-1000px{
     display:none;visibility:hidden;
    }
    #moon-for-plus800px,#moon-shadow-for-plus800px{
     display:block;visibility:visible;
    }
    }
    
    @media only screen and (min-width:1000px) and (max-width:1099px){
    .pegasus{
     width:70%;
     position:absolute;
     top:0%;z-index:9;left:15%;
    }
    .pegasus img{
     position:relative;
     left:-1%;width:100%;
    }
    .blue-band{
     width:100%;
     position:absolute;top:83%;
     background-color:transparent;z-index:9;
    }
    
    #moon-for-800px,#moon-shadow-for-800pxless,#moon-for-900px,#moon-shadow-for-900px,#moon-for-plus800px,#moon-shadow-for-plus800px{
     display:none;visibility:hidden;
    }
    
    #moon-for-1000px,#moon-shadow-for-1000px{
     display:block;visibility:visible;
    }
    }
    
    @media only screen and (min-width:900px) and (max-width:999px){
    .pegasus{
     width:70%;
     position:absolute;
     top:5%;z-index:9;left:15%;
    }
    .pegasus img{
     position:relative;
     left:-1%;width:100%;
    }
    .blue-band{
     width:100%;
     position:absolute;top:85%;
     background-color:transparent;z-index:9;
    }
    
    #moon-for-800px,#moon-shadow-for-800pxless,#moon-for-plus800px,#moon-shadow-for-plus800px,#moon-for-1000px,#moon-shadow-for-1000px{
     display:none;visibility:hidden;
    }
    #moon-for-900px,#moon-shadow-for-900px{
     display:block;visibility:visible;
    }
    }
    
    @media only screen and (min-width:800px) and (max-width:899px){
     #moon-for-plus800px,#moon-shadow-for-plus800px
    ,#moon-for-900px
    ,#moon-shadow-for-900px
    ,#moon-for-1000px
    ,#moon-shadow-for-1000px{
         display:none;visibility:hidden;
        }
     #moon-for-800px,#moon-shadow-for-800pxless{
         display:block;visibility:visible;
        }
    .pegasus{
     width:70%;
     position:absolute;
     top:20%;z-index:9;left:15%;
    }
    .pegasus img{
     position:relative;
     left:-1%;width:100%;
    }
    .blue-band{
     width:100%;
     position:absolute;top:87%;
     background-color:transparent;z-index:9;
    }
    }
```

Here, the div #moon-for-resolution is defined responsively using CSS. 
All this is done only to make parallax effect come across responsively. 
So, does this look like a correct approach in resolving my problem. 
Or is there any way to think which I am not aware of? 
Is there a java scripting way to go about it? 
If yes, then can somebody guide me on the scripting algorithm?
Please guide. Thanks much.:)

Comment: Yea..checked out many different sites and my work is going on for around seven months now. Made countless unsuccessful attempts in tryin to make it responsive. This is a workaround I came up. So, should I go ahead with this one?